# How can I make my Laplacian filter more efficient?

Tags: python, numpy

I made a Laplacian filter in python using numpy arrays and it works but it just takes a while (~15 seconds). I'm not sure how to go about making it faster. can't use any external libraries or image processing packages, only Numpy and PIL. Basically code from scratch.

```
data = numpy.array(image)
data = data.transpose(1,0,2)
laplace_filter = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, -4, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
for w in range(width+1):
   for h in range(height+1):
    for x in range(-block, block+1):
        for y in range(-block, block+1):
            if((x+w <= width-1) and (x+w >= 0) and (y+h <= height-1) and (y+h >= 0)): 
                data_temp[x][y] = data[w+x][h+y]
    data_temp = data_temp * laplace_filter
    data_temp = 255*((data_temp-data_temp.min())/((data_temp.max()*4)-data_temp.min()))
    for i in range(-block, block+1):
        for j in range(-block, block+1):
            if((i+w <= width-1) and (i+w >= 0) and (j+h <= height-1) and (j+h >= 0)):
                new_image[w+i][h+j] = data_temp[i][j]
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example by giving samples of data. You don't have to share the full image, just a random example with the shapes that you expect will do. We need to be able to reproduce your code without errors before making it faster.

Comment: @Ananda Oh I was just using Lenna test image passed through command line argument, 
[here is the pic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png)

And just converting that image to a numpy array with
image = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert("RGB")
data = numpy.array(image)